# What else am I missing to load service providers using the new Java module system?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I'm adding `module-info.java`s to [Ikonli](http://aalmiray.github.io/ikonli/) packages and I'm running into trouble with their service classes. `ikonli-core` defines an interface called [`IkonHandler`](https://github.com/aalmiray/ikonli/blob/master/subprojects/ikonli-core/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/IkonHandler.java). `ikonli-fontawesome5-pack` has [a service provider](https://github.com/aalmiray/ikonli/blob/master/subprojects/ikonli-fontawesome5-pack/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/fontawesome5/FontAwesomeSolidIkonHandler.java#L26) for the `IkonHandler` called [`FontAwesomeSolidIkonHandler`](https://github.com/aalmiray/ikonli/blob/master/subprojects/ikonli-fontawesome5-pack/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/fontawesome5/FontAwesomeSolidIkonHandler.java). These service prodivers are used by `ikonli-javafx`'s [`IkonResolver`](https://github.com/aalmiray/ikonli/blob/master/subprojects/ikonli-javafx/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/javafx/IkonResolver.java).

Given this, I created these module definitions:

```
module org.kordamp.ikonli.core {
    exports org.kordamp.ikonli;
}

module org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx {
    exports org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    uses org.kordamp.ikonli.IkonHandler;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;
}

module org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5 {
    exports org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5;
    provides org.kordamp.ikonli.IkonHandler with org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5.FontAwesomeBrandsIkonHandler, org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5.FontAwesomeRegularIkonHandler, org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5.FontAwesomeSolidIkonHandler;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;
    requires org.kordamp.jipsy;
}
```

They might not be complete, but they are complete enough so that when my application starts, it fails with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot resolve 'fas-user'
```

which is throw when no handler managed to [load the icon](https://github.com/aalmiray/ikonli/blob/master/subprojects/ikonli-javafx/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/javafx/IkonResolver.java#L53-L61):

```
public IkonHandler resolveIkonHandler(String value) {
    requireNonNull(value, "Ikon description must not be null");
    for (IkonHandler handler : HANDLERS) {
        if (handler.supports(value)) {
            return handler;
        }
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot resolve '" + value + "'");
}
```

The reason why that is happening is that `HANDLERS` is empty. `HANDLERS` is [loaded at startup by this code](https://github.com/aalmiray/ikonli/blob/master/subprojects/ikonli-javafx/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/javafx/IkonResolver.java#L37-L42):

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = IkonResolver.class.getClassLoader();
    ServiceLoader<IkonHandler> loader = ServiceLoader.load(IkonHandler.class, classLoader);
    for (IkonHandler handler : loader) {
        HANDLERS.add(handler);
        handler.setFont(Font.loadFont(classLoader.getResource(handler.getFontResourcePath()).toExternalForm(), 16));
    }
```

but with the module definitions quoted above, `ServiceLoader.load(IkonHandler.class, classLoader)` finds no service providers.

What am I missing?

Comment: From the [`ServiceLoader` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) , it recommends not to `exports org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5` ... *It is strongly recommended that the module does not export the package containing the service provider.* Also, to confirm `org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx` is the application module, right?

Comment: @nullpointer: `org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx` is a library, not the application (unless I'm misunderstanding the question). I removed the `exports org.krodamp.ikonli.fontawesome5`. I probably added it to try to get things to work. Without it I still get the same error though.

Comment: Run with `--show-module-resolution` to get a trace of the modules that are resolved at startup. If `org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx` is resolved then it should (by way of its `uses`) result in all modules that `provides org.kordamp.ikonli.IkonHandler` to be resolved.

Comment: `--show-module-resolution` showed me the problem. My app was not requiring the the fontawesome5 module. Yeah... I know... _facepalm_.

Comment: @pupeno The question I'd asked about application module was related to the same document quoting ... *In addition, if the service is not in the application module, then the module declaration must have a `requires` directive that specifies the module which exports the service.*... but seems like that was not the problem at your end anyway. Maybe the question could have been clear if you would have stated where you were actually executing and using all of the above.

Comment: @nullpointer: yeah, I'm sorry the question wasn't clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was missing was requiring `fontawesome5` in the `module-info.java` of my application:

```
requires org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5;
```

Comment: **Note to others**: Explicitly requiring the module that provides a service is not necessary. The module system automatically resolves all modules that provide a service needed by another resolved module. It is unclear why that didn't work in this case, but requiring the provider only papers over the actual problem.

Comment: What, even the ones in an air-gapped server somewhere in North Korea? How does it know what universe of possible modules to search to make that decision?

Answer (score 0):

"My app was not requiring the the fontawesome5 module."  Your app doesn't need to require it. In fact, your app shouldn't require it. You're missing the point of uses/provides.

*Edit* You make a provider available by putting it on the modulepath and watching the module system go to work. Your ikonli.javafx module uses the IkonHandler interface, and your ikonli.fontawesome5 module provides an implementation of the IkonHandler interface. That's all the module system needs to bind them together. It's wrong for ikonli.javafx to require ikonli.fontawesome5. ikonli.fontawesome5 shouldn't even export the package that it's exporting, because that allows anyone who requires ikonli.fontawesome5 to access the provider classes like FontAwesomeBrandsIkonHandler directly.

Comment: Hello @adfgh. You are getting some downvotes because Stack Overflow separates comments from answers and this is a comment (since it doesn't provide a solution to the problem). You can post it as a comment and delete the answer if you want. In Stack Overflow answers are expected to be self contained and a solution. I'm sorry you are getting downvotes instead of someone introducing you to the system. Sometimes Stack Overflow can be harsh when you are not following the rules perfectly.

Comment: I'd still be interested in know how do you make a provider available without requiring it.

Comment: `ikonli.javafx` is not requiring `ikonli.fontawesome5`, my application is.